# I am needing to drop some rows based on email address?

Tags: python, dataframe, data-analysis, data-wrangling

so I have a dataframe with some email addreses but I need to keep only corporate domain email address and discard the ones engind in gmail, hotmail, or yahoo.com

how can I do this?

```
dffinal['email']

4                  corporate@rocketbank.com.br
6                personal@gmail.com
7                    personal@gmail.com
9                 corporate@santander.com.br
11                corporate@revelo.fr
13          corporate@valemobi.com.br
```

I need to drop all results with personal emails and keep corporate ones.
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df[~df['email'].str.contains('gmail|hotmail|yahoo', regex=True)]
```

Get all rows where email does not contain those keywords